# Superimposing timeseries data on same plot by week - fixing my MultiIndex?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I have time series data which appears as follows

```
In[118]: df
Out[118]: 
                               Value
Date                                
2016-09-15 00:00:00.000000  0.446219
2016-09-15 00:10:07.958815  0.148335
2016-09-15 00:29:34.960880  0.300437
2016-09-15 00:40:38.262082  0.187721
2016-09-15 00:55:57.910574  0.108615
2016-09-15 01:15:29.595385  0.735744
2016-09-15 01:33:15.055574  0.167966
2016-09-15 01:47:47.570397  0.083261
                             ...
2017-01-19 14:09:11.347323  0.140574
2017-01-19 14:26:05.349305  0.122632
2017-01-19 14:38:02.607448  0.530922
2017-01-19 14:54:38.043359  0.983858
2017-01-19 15:06:36.638637  0.723228
2017-01-19 15:18:43.197898  0.380847
2017-01-19 15:33:03.925526  0.209378
2017-01-19 15:52:12.064726  0.969853
2017-01-19 16:03:07.974073  0.932526

[12175 rows x 1 columns]
```

I am trying to plot each week of this time series *on the same plot*, with the x-axis spanning the days of the week. With the help of a previous question I can now *nearly* accomplish this, by constructing a MultiIndex as follows. (*Here I only plot 4 weeks for simplicity*)

```
pl_df = df.copy()
pl_df.index = [df.index.weekday_name, df.index.time, df.index.to_period('w')]
ax = pl_df.Value.unstack().interpolate().iloc[:, :2].plot()
ax.figure.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image]

**The issue** is that the days of the week seem to be muddled, as one can see from looking at the x-axis. I attempted to use a simple list comprehension to reindex my DataFrame with a correct "day of the week" order such that the x-axis would appear correct, however this didn't seem to have any impact. I'm not even entirely sure the MultiIndex is correct, because of my interpretation of the output. I'm not really sure what is going on with the ordering of the indexes at all.

---

To generate a similar DataFrame, you can run the following

```
import datetime 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

start_date = datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15)
end_date = datetime.datetime.now()

dts = []
cur_date = start_date
while cur_date < end_date:
    dts.append((cur_date, np.random.rand()))
    cur_date = cur_date + datetime.timedelta(minutes=np.random.uniform(10, 20))


df = pd.DataFrame(dts, columns=['Date', 'Value']).set_index('Date')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ordered [`CategoricalIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.CategoricalIndex.html):

```
pl_df = df.copy()
cats = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday' ,'Friday' , 'Saturday','Sunday']

pl_df.index = [
    pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index.weekday_name, ordered=True, categories=cats), 
    df.index.time, 
    df.index.to_period('w')
]
ax = pl_df.Value.unstack().interpolate().iloc[:, :2].plot()
ax.figure.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image: graph]

Also you can use [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
pl_df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index.weekday_name, ordered=True, categories=cats), 
    df.index.time, 
    df.index.to_period('w')
])
```

Comment: @rtkaleta - Thank you for improve answer  - fixing indentation.

Comment: Thank you Jezrael, seems like there's always a tool in Pandas to use that I haven't had to pull out yet.

Comment: `Categorical` are not wide used, but for categorical data are very nice - save memory, you can order them. Thank you for accepting.

Comment: Ahh, categorical... nice